# What would 黑著臉 mean?

Tags: translation

黑著臉, Directly translating it, it would be "blacking his face", so is it something like "his face went dark" (Not even sure if that means anything or is proper in english).

Could it also be something like "his face was replaced with a scowl" or something similar?

Comment: Context?  Is it from a romance novel, a war movie, a role playing game?

Answer (score 3):

It means someone is not happy about things that are going on, it can be a disapprove to the decision other people made, anger about people's comment, behavior. 
黑 in this phrase describes a negative mood in one's face, as if someone is so mad at something, his/her heart begin beating faster, his/her face turns into a dark color than usual. Similarly you may see红着脸(flushed with fever or success or pride)， 绿着脸(bad stock market or unhappiness)，青着脸(angry or discontent about something). Other than color, there are also 板着脸，绷着脸，拉着脸，蒙着脸 etc.

Answer (score 1):

**汉语大辞典**

**黑**

> 6 脸色阴沉, 严厉。
>
> 沙汀 《困兽记》十七
>
> 他的语调逐渐流畅起来；但他忽然间
> 住了嘴, **黑着脸**一蹦站起来了。

**阴沉**

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> cloudy; overcast; gloomy; sombre

**严厉**

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> stern; severe

黑脸 = stern gloomy looking face

While 着 inductions the action of happening, turning, changing:

**Tuttle Learner's**

> (used after a verb to indicate the action or state is going on)

The above is far from comprehensive but it will suffice for our needs here.

Like the example from above:

> 他的语调逐渐流畅起来；但他忽然间
> 住了嘴, **黑着脸**一蹦站起来了。

The tone of his voice gradually softened, but then all of a sudden he stopped talking, his face went black (a gloomy solemness came over his face), and he jumped to his feet.

Here's entires for **黑脸** without the **着** same meaning just without the action:

**大汉语词典**

> 3 脸色阴沉。
>
> 欧阳山 《高干大》第五章
>
> ﹝高生亮﹞在 南沟 串了三天, 受尽多少闲气, 看尽多少黑脸, 还是不顶事。
>
> 古华 《丝竹园歌女》八
>
> 但后来就皱眉头, 就黑脸, 就瞪眼。

**两岸**

> 2 臉色陰沉；陰沉的臉色。
>
> 例：
>
> 他一生氣就～，怪嚇人的。
>
> 受盡多少閒氣，看盡多少～，事情還是沒有辦成。

Answer (score -2):

The Great God 百度, who knows all, has:

板着脸
显示出一种不开心或不满意的申请
不明白欢迎来追问!

Comment: 黑著臉 not 板着脸.....

Comment: Think you are a bit confused, try here, which is the answer to "黑着脸什么意思？“ http://zuoye.baidu.com/question/0e0f2f739e2de11f85bbbbdf91927091.html In general, I've found enter 'xxx 什么意思‘ in 百度 is very helpful!

Comment: The zhidao question doesn't really answer the question either. 答非所问. Zhidao is not really known for the best quality answers. 黑著臉 is not the same as 板着脸.

Comment: We, Chinese, consider 百度知道 as the worst site to ask any question. It just sucks.

Comment: Perhaps you would elaborate. How do ‘黑着脸’ and '板着脸‘ differ exactly? Are you saying you may not use them interchangeably?